# MySQL Select regular expression pattern to get value in json string

Tags: mysql, json, regex, select

I need some help on a MySQL REGEX_REPLACE pattern. I want to get the first value on a json string:

```
[{"lbl":"mobile","val":"987 654 321"},
{"lbl":"home","val":"123 456 789"}]

SELECT REGEX_REPLACE(`phones`, PATTERN, '') FROM table;
```

So, what I would like to get is **987 654 321**, What pattern would do the job?

Comment: What version are you using?  In the later versions, there are JSON functions to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: If `val` had its own column, then you would simply be `SELECT val FROM table;`  There are times to use `JSON`; I don't think this is one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extended solution using [***SUBSTRING***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) and [***LOCATE***](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) functions:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(chain,
        LOCATE('"val":"', phones) + 7,  -- considering offset as starting position for the final substring
        LOCATE('"}', phones, LOCATE('"val":"', phones)) - (LOCATE('"val":"', phones) + 7)) AS phone
FROM
    table
```

As `'"val":"'` occupies 7 chars, the *phone number* value should start at `LOCATE('"val":"', phones) + 7`

Comment: well, that's not bad at all, but it's not working with all records. And actually I do not understand why because it should. I.e: this value [{"lbl":"","val":" 944 606\u00a08##"}] , returns [{

Comment: @spacebiker, got it. That's because the first SUBSTRING_INDEX couldn't find `'"val":"'` at offset `-2` in your new example

Comment: I see, that's why I was asking for a Regex, we do not know the exact number of rows in the json, I need to find another solution but yet, your solution gave me some ideas..

Comment: I have some other ideas, but need your elaborations: is it always be static phone length `987 654 321` - nine numbers?

Comment: your are the man!  I was trying something similar but your solution works like a charm..

Comment: @spacebiker, glad to help